# Permanently prevent Windows from rearranging desktop icons

Tags: windows-10, desktop-customization, desktop-icons

I have a weird issue. Every now and then, seemingly at random, my desktop icons' positions reset to alphabetical order. I have them grouped by type -- all my games in one place, IDEs in another, etc. -- and it's incredibly frustrating to have to rearrange them.

This doesn't seem to happen after updates. It does, sometimes, but other updates don't change it, and it sometimes resets without an update. Auto-arrange icons is off, as is "allow themes to change desktop icons", I haven't changed my monitor resolution in six months<sup>1</sup>, and I've followed just about every piece of advice that didn't involve mucking with the registry, because I don't really like playing around with that on the say-so of some random person on the internet. This *keeps happening anyway*.

Short of installing some software, how can I permanently prevent Windows from rearranging my desktop icons? Is it possible?

---

<sup>1: Intentionally, at least. It's entirely possible that Windows is mucking with the resolution settings and hiding it from me.</sup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this problem. You did the steps I did as well when I was troubleshooting, but it just wasn't a permanent solution.

I ended up deleting all the icon caches in the local AppData folder. Mind that this is just a cache, so it's nothing that will be replaced thereafter once is caches your icons to rebuild the cache. This involves a bit of Command Prompt (or PowerShell, whichever you fancy).

1) Navigate to the following in Explorer (and of course, use your actual username):

```
C:\Users\YourUserName\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Explorer
```

2) Hold the 'Shift' key and right-click in the window, and in the menu click "Open command window here" (it may also say Power Shell).

3) To confirm you're in the right spot use the `dir` command. What populates should match the Explorer folder results.

4) Right-click on the taskbar and open the Task Manager (click more details if only the fewer details version is up).

5) Under the "Processes" tab, locate the "Windows Explorer" entry , right-click on it, and then click "end task" (as of course you may know, this will not break anything beyond making all the Windows Explorer items go away for the moment).

6) In Command Prompt (or Power Shell) enter `del iconcache*`.

7) Re-enter the `dir` command to ensure what was there before is now gone.

8) With Ctrl-Alt-Delete, sign off and sign back in and you should be good to go!

This is my first posted answer in StackExchange, so please let me know if this helps or if you have any comments!

Comment: Hey! I've done this, so now it's time to wait to see if my icons get rearranged _again_. Hopefully not. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Nope, they got rearranged again.

Comment: ...Okay, I feel a bit dumb. I just realized that I did this on my _laptop_, not the desktop that's been having this issue. Let me actually try this on the machine with problems and report back.

Comment: Haha! Made my heart sink for a moment. Hope it works for you.

Comment: Hopefully! This time I'll do it right, haha.

Comment: Hey! @NicHartley, just out of curiosity, did that fix work out for you?

Comment: It seems to be working fine! At the very least, it hasn't randomly reset again.

Comment: You could also use `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Explorer` if you paste that into the Explorer address bar - it will automatically fill in the drive and username for you.