# Desktop icons keep rearranging after reboot

Tags: windows, windows-10, icons, desktop

I've got a weird issue with my Windows 10 - after every restart it rearranges icons on desktop, since I've got multi-monitor setup it's a little bit annoying.
It looks like running a game in lower resolution than my primary display - icons that wouldn't fit on first screen are shifted to the secondary one, the rest is aligned to the game's resolution.
It happens every time I boot my PC, updating NVIDIA drivers didn't work, I also tried unchecking `Allow themes to change desktop icons` option in Windows settings and it also didn't help.

I've already tried removing `iconCache.db` file and did everything which was suggested here:
[Permanently prevent Windows from rearranging desktop icons](https://superuser.com/questions/1287183/permanently-prevent-windows-from-rearranging-desktop-icons)
without any effect.

Is it possible that file which contains info about icons arrangement is somewhere else?

Comment: It probalby started with alt-tabbing game, which run in a lower resolution and didn't support window switching since it crashed immediately after my desktop showed up.

Comment: After a reboot any issues software might have caused should have been reversed.  In fact any changes to the software made to the Desktop should have been reversed when the process ended.

Comment: @Ramhound unfortunatelly it looks like it affected system for good, any changes to icons arrangement seem to be dismissed every time I boot pc.